# Why does the sticky navbar doesnt working in Laravel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to do a sticky navbar which the navbar will be static even when scrolling down the page. I tried using the code below, However it doesnt work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-sticky-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
            </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/">Register</a></li>
                </ul>


            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

What should I fix so the sticky navbar will be function well?

Comment: Which version of `bootstrap` you are using ? and also please mention the version of `laravel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this CSS in your header section

```
.navbar-sticky-top
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity:1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#fixed-navbar) also:

```
<nav class="navbar is-fixed-top">
```